# Deserialize JsonObjects to .NET Objects

Tags: c#, json.net

Attempting to deserialize the following JSON into a .NET object using Json.Net isn't working out as intended. Deserializing usually isn't a major complication, but the structure of the following JSON isn't as straight forward.

JSON:

```
{
    "33": {
        "0": {
            "StopName": "JFK Blvd & 15th St",
            "Route": "33",
            "date": "11:24p",
            "day": "Fri",
            "Direction": "1",
            "DateCalender": "02/10/12 11:24 pm"
        },
        "3": {
            "StopName": "JFK Blvd & 15th St",
            "Route": "33",
            "date": "11:52p",
            "day": "Fri",
            "Direction": "1",
            "DateCalender": "02/10/12 11:52 pm"
        }
    },
    "32": {
        "1": {
            "StopName": "JFK Blvd & 15th St",
            "Route": "32",
            "date": "11:30p",
            "day": "Fri",
            "Direction": "1",
            "DateCalender": "02/10/12 11:30 pm"
        }
    },
    "17": {
        "2": {
            "StopName": "JFK Blvd & 15th St",
            "Route": "17",
            "date": "11:38p",
            "day": "Fri",
            "Direction": "1",
            "DateCalender": "02/10/12 11:38 pm"
        }
    }
}
```

The complication results from "33", "32", "17" which represent route numbers. These numbers can change as the routes in the result set change.

I'm sure I'll need to write a custom JSON converter for this, but I can't find any clear information on accomplishing this task (as no one seems to have a problem where the property name is dynamic).

I attempted also to use JSON.NET Linq to JSON, but this isn't feasible because you need to use code similar to the following to access the JSON:

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(e.Result);
o["33"];
```

Since I have no realistic idea what the property names are before hand I can't easily traverse this object it seems.

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Your json format :

```
{
    "33": { <-- This is MainRoute number
        "0": { <-- This is SubRoute number and below are SubRoute properties
            "StopName": "JFK Blvd & 15th St",
            "Route": "33",                        
            "date": "11:24p",                   
            "day": "Fri",
            "Direction": "1",
            "DateCalender": "02/10/12 11:24 pm"
        },
     ....
}
```

You can use `JObject` to parse your json data :

```
public class MainRoute {
        public int RouteNumber { get; set; }
        public IList<SubRoute> SubRoutes { get; set; }

        public MainRoute()
        {
                SubRoutes = new List<SubRoute>();
        }
}

public class SubRoute {
        public int RouteNumber { get; set; }
        public string StopName { get; set; }
        public int Route { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("date")]
        public string Date { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("day")]
        public string Day { get; set; }
        public int Direction { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("DateCalender")]
        public string DateCalendar { get; set; }
}

class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                string jsonString = FetchJsonData();
                var routes = ParseRouteJsonString(jsonString);
        }

        static IEnumerable<MainRoute> ParseRouteJsonString(string jsonString)
        {
                JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> pair in jsonObject) {
                        var mainRoute = new MainRoute() {
                                RouteNumber = Int32.Parse(pair.Key) // Get main route number.
                        };

                        foreach (JProperty property in pair.Value) {
                                var subRoute = property.Value.ToObject<SubRoute>();
                                subRoute.RouteNumber = Int32.Parse(property.Name); // Get sub route number.
                                mainRoute.SubRoutes.Add(subRoute);
                        }

                        yield return mainRoute;
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a small sample of how to iterate through the routes using linq to json:

```
var main = JObject.Parse(json);
foreach (var mainRoute in main.Properties())
{
    Console.WriteLine(mainRoute.Name); //33, 32, ... 
    foreach (var subRoute in mainRoute.Values<JObject>().SelectMany(x => x.Properties()))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" " + subRoute.Name); //0, 3, ... 
        var routeData = subRoute.Value as JObject;
        foreach (var dataItem in routeData.Properties())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("  {0} = {1}", dataItem.Name, dataItem.Value.Value<string>()));
        }
    }
}
```